# How to minimize salt taste from biryani?

Tags: salt, rice, vegan

I've tried Veg Biryani dish yesterday but I was failed to know the amount of salt to be added.
Its tasting little bit salty. I've to cook it again today night. Can somebody tell me how to reduce the salty taste in case Veg Biryani or any dish?

For person who don't know Veg Biryani:
http://www.vegrecipesofindia.com/hyderabad-veg-biryani-hyderabadi-vegetable-dum-biryani-recipe/

Comment: I hesitate to say this lest I sound facetious but... use less salt?

Comment: Dear ElendilTheTall, If some dish is perfectly done but ruined just because of bit extra salt then should someone throw it in dustbin??

Comment: Are you saying you are cooking a new biryani tonight or you are reheating the same, over-salted one? It is not clear from your question. Naturally if you are reheating the salty one there is little you can do.

Comment: I want to reheat the yesterday's biryani also and want to cook new one again and also in case this situation will occur may in future then want some solution that will solve this case.

Comment: Well, in future when you cook the biryani, use less salt. As for reheating yesterday's biryani, did you cool it quickly or did you let it cool at room temperature?

Comment: @TheDK there isn't anything you can do to remove salt from an already cooked dish. You can dilute the dish with something you think fits the taste, or cook a second batch without salt and all and mix the two batches. But salt, once added, won't go away.

Comment: Thanks rumtscho. Your suggestion sounds prolific rather the taunts passing on this question.

Comment: And thanks to Mien to informing that this kind of question already asked here. I'll refer it for future purpose.

Comment: Oh boy ...well if a briyani has gotten too salty then you are forced to either make Iit again or make a side dish like "rhita" without salt. Then again rhita is yoghurt based - to say sour. Latter had worked for me anyway. Also if you are making plain briyani not "dum" then you are better of with rumtscho's "mix a second batch of saltless cooked rice to your salty rice" idea.